# Display X3D file with ARKit

Tags: swift, swift3, augmented-reality, x3d, arkit

I need to display an X3D file from a server in a room with Apple's new ARKit.

How is it possible to display an X3D file with Apple ARKit?
In general - what are the supported file formats for ARKit/Scene Kit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You will need to either write your own loader for the Model I/O API, or find one that someone else has created.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/610/

2) Build an application that performs a conversion from X3D to one of the supported Model I/O formats such as USD or Collada.

I note that X3D is XML serialised, that would mean that a transform to Collada could be created with an XSLT style sheet.